# Pandas Depreciated Package, trying to update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I update this depreciated package?

Code:

```
def M_A_C_D( df, f, s):
   fast_ema = pd.ewma( df['Close'], span=f)
   slow_ema = pd.ewma( df['Close'], span=s)
   macd = fast_ema - slow_ema
   return slow_ema
```

Error

FutureWarning: pd.ewm_mean is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a 
   future version, replace with 
   Series.ewm(span=12,min_periods=0,adjust=True,ignore_na=False).mean()

My attempt

```
def M_A_C_D( df, f, s):
  fast_ema = df['Close'].ewm(span=f)
  slow_ema = df['Close'].ewm(span=s)
  macd = fast_ema - slow_ema
  return slow_ema
```

Error

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'EWM' and 'EWM'

My 2nd attempt

```
def M_A_C_D( df, f, s):
  fast_ema = df['Close'].ewm(span=f).mean()
  slow_ema = df['Close'].ewm(span=s).mean()
  macd = fast_ema - slow_ema
  return slow_ema
```

Message:I dont know why it is giving me this.  I wanted macd-fast_ema-slow_ema?  I am so confused :(

```
def MACD(df,period1,period2,periodSignal): EMA1 = 
   pd.DataFrame.ewm(df,span=period1).mean() EMA2 = 
   pd.DataFrame.ewm(df,span=period2).mean() MACD = EMA1-EMA2
   Signal = pd.DataFrame.ewm(MACD,periodSignal).mean()

   Histogram = MACD-Signal

   return Histogram
```

Comment: Your second attempt looks reasonable. You don't show the message it gives though - just some more code trying to use DataFrames instead of a Series (as an aside: you `return slow_ema` instead of `macd`...)

Comment: @JonClements my second attempt gave me some weird message when I tried to call the function.  I have no clue why it is returning me the function code in itself

Comment: Is that weird message super top secret or are you going to say what it is and how you call the function so someone might be able to help explain it? :) (I'm guessing you have a stack trace that happens to be including portions of your code for context to show where the error is occurring - you need to [edit] that into your question)

Comment: @JonClements I posted the message in the question, right underneath 2nd attempt.

Comment: You wouldn't get that if you got an error - it's not even the same code as the attempt you posted -  are you sure you're not getting a stack trace or have attempted code like that example and left it in somewhere?

Comment: @JonClements i restarted the kernal and ran it again.  even did a control+f i have no clue where EMA1 or any of that message code is coming from

Comment: same issue today with me , did you find the solution ? its 2 years and there is no answer till now !!